# How to make 2 overlapping <div>s to be shown after one another by clicking a href and a button from another <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a brief sample of my code:

```
<body>

<div class="ContentDiv">


    +------------+--------------+
    | [checkbox] | file1 | view |   view is a hyperlink 
    +------------+--------------+
    | [checkbox] | file2 | view |   
    +------------+--------------+

    <a href="view.php" target="outputframe">View</a>

    +------------------+
    | Compare selected |    Compare selected is a button
    +------------------+

    <input type="submit" class="button green" value="Compare selected"/>

</div>

<div class="Output1" id="Output1">
    <iframe src="view.php" name="outputframe" height="110px" width="500px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</div>

<div class="Output2" id="Output2">
    <compare> comparisons of files functions...</compare>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('?').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
                jQuery('#Output2').hide();
                jQuery('#Output1').show();
        });
        jQuery('?').click(function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               jQuery('#Output1').hide();
               jQuery('#Output2').show();
        });
</script>

</body>
```

I've already familiar using the javascript, which can make two different div to show after one another by clicking (for example) button 'table' to show TableDiv and button 'histogram' to show HistogramDiv.

The problem now is that I don't know how to apply the same thing for a href which is in a table and a button from inside a form to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
jQuery('input[type="submit"][value="Compare selected"]').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
                jQuery('#Output1').toggle();
                jQuery('#Output2').toggle();
        });
```

First set display property for #Output1 and #Output2 with css which to show and which to hide.

Comment: can this be applied for the href too? I've already tried your answer. The Output2 hides Output1 after clicked, but when I clicked the 'view' href, doesn't display Output1 nor hides Output2. 

I've also set the visibility like you suggested. @C-link

Comment: Yes you can use this for href too and not visibility but display.... toggle works for display not visibility